# Set Different Scroll Speeds for j/k Keys and Touchpad in Zathura?

Tags: zathura

I've recently made adjustments to my Zathura PDF viewer's scrolling settings by adding set scroll-step 1 to my .zathurarc configuration file, aiming to slow down the scrolling speed. However, this change also affected the j/k keys, making their scrolling much slower than I'd like.

Is there a way to set independent scroll speeds for the j/k keyboard shortcuts and the touchpad in Zathura? I'd like to retain the slower touchpad scroll but have a faster scroll with the j/k keys.